# change daily chart close time setting

Tags: time, pine-script

How do I change my pine script "close - close(1)" in a daily chart, in order not to receive the close from UTC 0.00 but 5 minutes earlier, comparing closes from 23.55?

Comment: Evening, what time frame/symbol are you using? Are you after a plot line?